SNS topic subscription body filter not working on values over 5 billion
I have an SNS topic with a subscription to a Lambda function with a filter policy scope on the message body with this definition:
{
  "size": [
    {
      "numeric": [
        ">",
        0
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I use the size attribute filter to filter out any folder creations. We realized that large file object creation events were not making it through our topic to the Lambda. After exploring the topic manually, we realized the subscription is filtering out any message where the value of the size attribute is over 5x10^9 (5,000,000,000). Publishing these messages works:
{"size": 4999999999}
{"size": 5000000000}

but publishing a message like this does not get picked up by the subscription.
{"size": 50000000001}

I don't see any in the SNS topic subscription policy details that indicates there is this kind of limit on the values for this comparison. It seems like such an arbitrary value as well. Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

From this page under "Numeric range" it appears that you've done better than the stated plus/minus 10^9.
